# Huawei Matebook Xpro 2021 Fingerprint issue

Tags: laptop, fingerprint-reader, huawei

I was wondering does anyone could use the fingerprint on their Huawei laptop? I tried in different ways but the fingerprint never display in the user setting. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Edit your post to include `lsusb` terminal command output